# Identificar propriedade de um Object no Java+JPA e alterá-la

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou criando uma classe para obter o registro de um banco de dados e gravar em outro banco de dados.

Estou usando `JPA` e esbarrei em um problema. Estou fazendo um **inserção genérica** e tenho que limpar o `ID` da tabela para poder inserir, como chega para mim um `Object` eu não sei qual o campo limpar e nem como...

Preciso de duas coisas então, identificar qual a propriedade da classe é `@Id` e como limpá-la.

No código abaixo coloquei um comentário `aqui` mostrando onde está a incógnita.

```
class InsertObject implements Runnable {

    private final int integrationId;
    private final Class entityClass;
    private final EntityManager emOrigem;
    private final EntityManager emDestino;

    public InsertObject(int integrationId, Class entityClass, EntityManager emOrigem, EntityManager emDestino) {
        this.integrationId = integrationId;
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.emOrigem = emOrigem;
        this.emDestino = emDestino;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // carrega objeto origem
        String sql = "SELECT x FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " x WHERE integracaoId = " + integrationId;
        Query qOrigem = emOrigem.createQuery(sql);
        Object oOrigem = qOrigem.getSingleResult();

        // remove id
        emOrigem.detach(oOrigem);
        //oOrigem.setId(null); // <<<< AQUI <<<<<<<<<

        // salva no destino
        emDestino.getTransaction().begin();
        emDestino.persist(oOrigem);
        emDestino.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode buscar pelo atributo (aqui representado pela classe **Field**) que possua a anotação **@Id**. Uma vez encontrado, você usa o método **Field.set** do próprio atributo encontrado para setar o seu valor para *null*.

```
for (Field atributo: oOrigem.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    Id anotacaoId = atributo.getAnnotation(Id.class);
    if (anotacaoId != null) {
        atributo.setAccessible(true);
        atributo.set(oOrigem, null);
    }    
}
```

Note que o objeto encontrado é uma instância de um metadado da classe, e não uma referência para o atributo do objeto em si. De modo que o método **set** pede também a instância do objeto cujo atributo você quer setar (**oOrigem**) além do valor que você quer setar (**null**).

A anotação **@Id** quando atribuída a um campo da classe, geralmente este campo é *private* ou *protected*. Por isso eu usei do método **setAccessible** é para torná-lo acessível; de outro modo ocorreria uma exceção de membro inacessível.